# Unwanted JSON Response

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm using this small JSON function with a database.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   var url = "Database.php";
   $("#jsondata tbody").html("");
   $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
       $.each(data.users, function (i, user) {
           var songdetails = "<p>"
                   + "<p>" + user.Title + "</p>"
                   + "<p>" + user.ArtistNumber + "</p>"
                   + "<p>" + user.TrackTime + "</p>"
                   + "<p>" + user.Composer + "</p>"
                   + "<p>" + user.Lyricist + "</p>"
               + "</p>";

           $(songdetails).appendTo("songlist");

       });
   });
});
</script>
```

This produces this in the browser, which I don't want/need.

> {"users":[{"Title":"Anyway","ArtistNumber":"2","TrackTime":"167","Composer":"John
>   Glaze","Lyricist":"Kellee
>   Maize","FileLocation":"public/Anyway.mp3","rated":"0","scores":"[0,0,0,0,0]","free":"0"},{"Title":"One
>   Way Heartbeats","ArtistNumber":"4","TrackTime":"187","Composer":"Bill
>   Bobs","Lyricist":"Michael
>   McEachern","FileLocation":"public/OneWayHeartbeats.mp3","rated":"0","scores":"[0,0,0,0,0]","free":"0"},{"Title":"Parallel
>   Me","ArtistNumber":"3","TrackTime":"192","Composer":"Quite
>   Revolution","Lyricist":"Quite
>   Revolution","FileLocation":"private/ParallelMe.mp3","rated":"0","scores":"[0,0,0,0,0]","free":"1"},{"Title":"Poisoned
>   Oxygen","ArtistNumber":"3","TrackTime":"177","Composer":"Quite
>   Revolution","Lyricist":"Quite
>   Revolution","FileLocation":"public/PoisonedOxygen.mp3","rated":"0","scores":"[0,0,0,0,0]","free":"0"},{"Title":"Xmas
>   Prison Blues","ArtistNumber":"1","TrackTime":"192","Composer":"Steve
>   Perry","Lyricist":"Steve
>   Perry","FileLocation":"private/XmasPrisonBlues.wma","rated":"0","scores":"[0,0,0,0,0]","free":"1"}]}

Any ideas on how to hide it or remove it from coming up? 
Thanks

This is the Database.php:

```
<?php

$Hostserver = "localhost";
$databUser = "ee2800";
$databPass = "secret";
$databDatabase = "ee2800";

$database = new mysqli ($Hostserver, $databUser, $databPass, $databDatabase);

if ($database) {
mysqli_select_db($database, "ee2800");
//echo ("Successfully connected to database!");
} else {
    die ("<strong>Error:</strong> Failed to connect to the database.");
}

$var = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs";

$result = mysqli_query($database, $sql);

while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

    $var[] = $obj;
}

echo '{"users":' . json_encode($var) . '}';
?>
```

Using jQuery 1.10.2
The songlist element is found here

```
<?php 
             // The system queries the database to obtain a result set containing no more than 10 artists //
            if ($result = $database->query( "SELECT * FROM `artist` ORDER BY `artist`.`ArtistNumber` ASC LIMIT 10")) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                    echo "<div id='artist{$row[2]}'>";
                    echo "<p>Artist: {$row[0]} {$row[1]}</p>";
                    echo '<p><a href="#Songs" id="song' . $row[2] . '"><div id= songlist> </div> </a></p>';
            //div tag 'songlist' adds all data from json and pastes into this div id // 
             //      echo '<p><a href="#" id="songlist' . $row[2] . '">Songs</a></p>'; 
        //onlick function echo'd anchor tag// 
                    echo "</div>";
// Songs dont display onclick however retrieved data using jSON can't seem to target where to put the information //
                }
            }
            $database->close();
        ?>
```

And basically whenever I run these files, I get that long string I stated at the beginning as a response in my browser everytime.

Comment: Can we have `Database.php`?

Comment: Database edited into question now.

Comment: Edit your question with proper code formatting.

Comment: Yep just did so :), new to this website, sorry boys.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Also, this bit: `$(songdetails).appendTo("songlist");` looks for an **element** named _songlist_, which means you should have the tags "<songlist>" somewhere in your HTML, are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. You mean that you can see the actual JSON shown on your page? If so, your JavaScript code does not seem to cause that problem (although it does have problems). Is your page generated with php? (Database.php appart). If so, right click on your page and click View source. If you can see that JSON in the source, then the problem is in your page's PHP.

Comment: Is the JSON visible in the browser before the `$.getJSON` is invoked?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but as others have said it seems like the problem stems from my PHP and not the JSON. This is for a web application project btw, just to give some context it's supposed to contain a few artists and their songs which the users can access.

Answer (score 0):

Well your PHP appears to be returning a valid json string, but it is not being coverted automatically to a json object so that it can be processed by javascript as an object.

You could try forcing the parse to a json object like this

```
 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
   $.each(data.users, function (i, user) {
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` already parses it, no need to do it twice. _"The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array"_ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @blex I know thats what should be happening, but how do you explain the raw json string being produced into the HTML?

Comment: _I think_ the issue is with the page's PHP, not with the JS. Because nothing in his JS would cause the JSON to magically appear on the page (if it's not being parsed, it'll just fail, not print it on the page as is).

Comment: Any ideas as to what mistakes there could be with my PHP? or how I could show you the mistakes?

Comment: Are you using the browsers javascript debugger?